# Sending error as JSON to the front-end using HttpServletResponse

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, servlets

I am working on a REST backend and I have a requirement to send error  information (messages together with custom application keys & codes) as JSON back to the front end.

I am not sure whether to include the JSON in the `msg` argument to the `sendError` method (from `HttpServletResponse`) as follows:

```
void sendError(int sc,
               java.lang.String msg)
               throws java.io.IOException
```

... or use the response's actual payload as follows:

```
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

Can anyone please advise as to which is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sendError` will set the content type to `"text/html"`and as such is not a good candidate for pushing custom json error messages to the client.

You're better off setting the statuscode yourself

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

and then writing the JSON string you want using the writer.

This is obviously very low-level. If you're using some kind of REST framework it typically has good support for automatically translation exceptions into a JSON format. That way you simply need to throw an exception and the framework will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks for this reply! Do you have a specific framework in mind for avoiding the low level drudge?

Comment: Spring is pretty good. (basic tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). You can customize the exception handling by providing custom ExceptionHandlers (https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)